# Shopify API CakePHP Unauthorized 401 after token received

Tags: shopify

I am working on patching the shopify interface available [here](https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/CakePHP-Shopify-Plugin) for CakePHP based on the code from [another project](https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php) having a similar behavior by the same author implementing OAuth2.

I managed to iron out most of the things and I've ended up with an issue that I am unsure on how to solve related to the Shopify API.

When doing the authentication, I receive all the information stated by the Authentication document (http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html) provided by shopify, I have corrected the validation methods and I end up with the right verification md5 value based on the provided calculation method.

I can install the application and load my base controller, however, upon trying to pass an API call, I end up with a 401 error on the page:

```
[errors] => [API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password).
```

I have checked most of the code over and over and I can't seem to find where things are going wrong.

On a side note: I have tried to perform the command manually using curl as follows and see if I get a positive output:

```
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token:<<token>>" https://<<shopify-domain>>/admin/shop.json
```

This is the output:

```
{"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}
```

For some reason, the access token that I am receiving from the shopify API does not seem to work.

Also, I'm trying this on a test shop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have found the issue and have managed to correct it. For those interested, there is an additional step required to obtain the actual access token: contrarily to what is stated by the Shopify API documentation on Authenticating an app, the access token is actually provided by the call to "https://<<shopify-domain>>/admin/oauth/access_token" with client_id, client_secret and code POST parameters.

Comment: Where did you find the incorrect instructions? We'd like to fix the problem if there's bad info in our docs :)

Comment: David, after re-reading the API auth page, I noticed that there was no mistake, rather I read it incorrectly and managed to fix it. Apologies for the incorrect statement I made previously. It was a long night...

Comment: No worries, glad you got everything working :)